# why sorting algorithm takes zero seconds

Tags: c++, time

here is algorithm

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a[10]={12,3,5,2,7,80,10,1,16,30};
    long ts,te;
    srand(::GetTickCount());
    ts=clock();
     for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
       for (int j=9;j>i;j--){

                  if (a[j]<a[j-1]){

                   int t=a[j];a[j]=a[j-1];a[j-1]=t;

                  }

       }



     }

       te=clock();
       cout<<" time elapsed "<<te-ts<<endl;




 return 0;
}
```

but i am surprise ,because it gives me zero as output,i am measuring  time elapsed from begining of code to  finishing,and why?my computer  is not  so called supercomputer  and what is wrong  in this code fragment?

Comment: please check that it doesn't return `–1`.

Comment: what is resolution of clock() call? sorting 10 numbers should take a few milliseconds at most....

Comment: You should be using clock_t for ts and te (which may be long, but still...)

Comment: even bubble sort is fast if n is small

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you used punch-cards to write your program, you shouldn't be surprised that sorting 10 numbers takes less than one tick. If you want a more accurate profile of your code, use milliseconds, that should give you a better idea.

The inner-most instruction in the loops run 100 times - that's nothing compared to even a low-end processor nowadays.

EDIT: I tested the code with 100000 numbers, that's 10^10 iterations inside the for loop, and it only took 3 seconds.

Comment: For a modern computer, even milliseconds will be too small to measure sorting 10 numbers. Either use a bigger sample or use a microsecond timer to measure.

Comment: @KerrekSB i think that's it, clock() returns milliseconds but this can't possibly take more than the resolution you specified.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be surprised that sorting ten numbers takes less than one tick of the clock. Repeat the sorting many times to get meaningful timings.

My computer takes 0.18 seconds to run 1 million repetitions of your loop with with the exact same starting array. Therefore each sort takes about 180 microseconds. This is much too fine to measure with a pair of `clock()` calls.

Comment: But did you scramble the array between sorting it?

Comment: @UncleBens: I did. The test was run 1,000,000 times with the exact same starting array.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more accurate time measurment using a high resolution timer.
see http://www.songho.ca/misc/timer/timer.html
The time you're trying to measure leaves in the ranges of microseconds!